# How to process all requests with one php script?

Tags: apache, apache2

How to process with apache2 all requests by one script? Without mods if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've did it with DocumentRoot:

```
DocumentRoot *site*/index.php
```

It generates warning, but it's working:

```
Warning: DocumentRoot [*site*/index.php] does not exist
```

Comment: That's because it is not allowed (and it doesn't make sense) to use * in DocumentRoot. If /path/to/index.php as DocumentRoot works it's I think ok, but better way to get this working id to use mod_alias (AliasMatch) or mod_rewrite

Comment: i've hiden path with *site*, the path is /home/miroslav/htdocs/... :)

Answer (score 0):

Generate URLs such as `/index.php/topic/4/thread/3/` and then examine `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`. Or just use normal query strings and use `$_GET`.

Comment: Then you have no choice but to use something like mod_rewrite. mod_php isn't designed to multiplex everything through one script on its own.

Answer (score 0):

use mod_rewrite, really. This is what it was made fore. Put something like this into .htaccess or the apache config:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|javascript|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This sends all requests except to some subdirectories you might want available for CSS, images, javascript, as well as files you want available such as robots.txt or favicon.ico to your index.php file, with the actual file requested added to the URL so index.php can process the request.